# Betonung von Mephistopheles

Tags: pronunciation

Ich habe hauptsächlich die Variante gefunden, in der das **o** betont wird, aber es gibt einige, die behaupten, dass die Betonung auf dem vorletzten e liegt (Betonung auf o und e: [1](http://www.gutefrage.net/frage/faust-wie-spricht-man-mephistopheles-aus), Betonung auf o: [2](http://de.forvo.com/word/mephistopheles/)).

Gibt es Regeln oder eine maßgebende Quelle, anhand derer man argumentieren kann ob die Betonung nun

Mephist**o**pheles oder 
Mephistoph**e**les ist?

Comment: Sag einfach _Mephisto_. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Da die etymologische Ableitung des Namens offen ist – es gibt mehrere einander widersprechende Theorien –, ist es schwierig, die zutreffenden Regeln zu identifizieren.

Mit maßgeblichen Quellen ist es einfacher: Wörterbücher, wie das Duden-Aussprachewörterbuch oder der Rechtschreib-Wahrig, setzen die Betonung auf das *o*.

Answer (score 0):

Eine Faustregel, die ich mal gehört habe und die sehr gut funktioniert, ist, bei Wörtern aus dem Altgriechischen die drittletzte Silbe zu betonen. Hier würde also das o betont, und das hört sich für mich auch richtig an.

Edit: Ich gebe zu, dass die Regel nicht auf Wörter mit weniger als vier Silben angewandt werden sollte. Und sicher wird es Ausnahmen geben, aber in Fällen, *in denen ich mir unsicher war*, fand ich sie oft hilfreich.

Comment: Wie zum Beispiel in Strategie, Didaktik, Hologramm, Hypothese, Mikroskop, Psychologe, Bibliothek usw. usf.?

Comment: Ok, dann wenden wir die Regel nur für Wörter mit mehr als drei Silben an.

Comment: Wie zum Beispiel in Hypothese, Psychologe, Bibliothek, Arachnophobie, Chronologie, Hypotenuse, Fotografie, Astrophysik usw. usf.?

Comment: Ok, ich sehe es ein.

Comment: Ein Körnchen Wahrheit steckt allerdings drin: Wegen der Betonungsregeln im Griechischen und Lateinischen kann im Normalfall die Betonung nicht _vor_ der drittletzten Silbe liegen. Aber ob die drittletzte, vorletzte oder letzte Silbe betont wird, ist komplizierter, und man muß einiges über das zugrundeliegende Wort wissen.

Comment: Hahahha... Eine Faustregel. Wie treffend.

Comment: Die Regel trifft wohl eher fuer's Englische zu, STRAtegy, HyPOtenuse, MIcroscope, etc.